How might one define an object which does not have any fixed properties?
The naive view is that a class of objects can be defined by identifying a property which each of the members have, and which no non-members have.
This is obviously too much to hope for in most circumstances, but nevertheless provides a starting point. I'm aware also of attempts of defining classes of objects by the use of 'familial resemblance' which can be made concrete by the use of probability functions.
I was wondering what accounts are given of how an object might be defined in the absence of fixed properties. For example, one might have an object 'x' and it has properties 'a', 'b', 'c' and time 't_0', but these are not fixed and change to 'd', 'e', 'f' and time 't_1'.
Moreover, can anyone recommend any texts which deal with something like a philosophy of definitions or a theory of definitions?
Edit:
Also, I'm looking for answer which isn't "Object x is the object which has properties 'a', 'b', 'c' and time 't_0' and 'd', 'e', 'f' and time 't_1', etc". Something more elegant than this would nice.
Thank you!

Any formula of predicate calculus with a single free variable defines a class of objects that satisfy it, this is too broad for a distinction between "fixed" and time-varying "properties" (1-place predicates) to make sense. You can have no "properties" in that formula at all, only relations (multi-place predicates), and your relations can have a time variable in them, which results in different "properties" at different times. So ∀t P(x,t) defines a class of objects that satisfy a time-varying "property" P(x,t) (it is a 1-place predicate for each fixed t).

This question is too vague. What is an example of something that has no fixed properties but you want to define it anyway?

@DavidGudeman What about a cloud in sky?

@JoWehler, a cloud as a location in space, a visual appearance, and other properties.

I think, If an "object" doesn't have fixed properties but rather could be described over time, that description and how it operated would be it's fixed property.  It's "objectness" would be that which you could say about it the description.

@variableization Yes, that sounds right to me. I was merely hoping for some elaboration on this thought.

Shouldn't the method or criteria used derive from the end goal to classify the object?  For example, if I'm sorting recyclables I would classify by material, (plastic, glass, etc.) but if I need containers I would sort by function.  (cans and bottles in the same bin...). Why are you classifying things in the first place? Define your need and the answer should be apparent, no?  Or is this another esoteric "philosophy" question about the mundane?

@JoWehler I don't say that a cloud has no fixed properties, but you have failed to name any i.e. location in space and visual appearance are both subject to literally continual change.

@MichaelHall To classify an object, and to define it, are not the same. I think your point is valid (i.e. what is your purpose) iff my intention was to classify an object. I don't wish to classify some object/s as belonging to some categories. I wish to formulate a description of an object/s which exactly mark out the object in question and nothing else. To what purpose? Well, for the common purpose of giving nouns meaning in the context of a broader language. But maybe I've missed your point, is what I wrote convincing?

Ok, but how is "defining a class of objects" substantially different than defining and classifying them?  Either way, my point is that the process should be pragmatic and purpose driven.
